# Проблема с Jackson не десериализует файл

Tags: java, json, java-ee, jackson

есть вот такой код

```
public Object deserialize(String string, Object object) {
    try {
        return jackson.readValue(string, object.getClass());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.info("not able to serialize the json to object");
    }
    return null;
}
```

На вход ему даем строку json и объект в который нужно десеарилизовать этот json.
Но тут у нас вылетает ошибка решение которой я не смог найти в интернете.
вот и сама ошибка

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type java.sql.Timestamp from String "2016-02-19 10:33:28.0": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2016-02-19 10:33:28.0': Unparseable date: "2016-02-19 10:33:28.0")
 at [Source: {"has_image":0,"has_audio":0,"updated_at":"2016-02-19 10:33:28.0","title_contains":"ddddd","origin":"facebook","created_at":"2016-02-19 10:33:28.0","origin_id":3,"id":12,"title_not_contain":"aa","has_video":1,"has_file":0}; line: 1, column: 43] (through reference chain: jsmarty.core.router.model.GarbageRule["updated_at"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:74)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1374)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:925)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:822)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseDate(StdDeserializer.java:791)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$DateBasedDeserializer._parseDate(DateDeserializers.java:172)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$TimestampDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:309)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers$TimestampDeserializer.deserialize(DateDeserializers.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:490)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2833)
    at jsmarty.core.common.json.JsonHandler.deserialize(JsonHandler.java:83)
    at jsmarty.core.router.model.SdoRouteDataParser.toGarbageRules(SdoRouteDataParser.java:78)
    at jsmarty.core.router.PathManager.updateRulesPaths(PathManager.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at jsmarty.core.common.scheduling.ScheduledTask.run(ScheduledTask.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: А что в самом классе? Как там updated_at, created_at объявлены?

Comment: @Russtam переменные updated_at, created_at   тип Date

Comment: раньше использовался Genson с ним все было хорошо) но сейчас использовать Genson не могу.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations пункт 3.5 , скорее всего такую штуку надо для этих полей.